# ListView obscuring sibling views?

Tags: android, android-layout

I can't seem to get the footer navigation bar to show up in this layout. It's obscured by the ListView *no matter how I set* layout_weight on the navigation bar *or* change the layout_height of the ListView to one of FILL_PARENT or WRAP_CONTENT. Any ideas how  to get the correct result? Essentially, I want the footer to be fixed at the bottom of the screen.

(BTW, I need to keep the nested LinearLayouts. However, I can change them to other ViewGroups.)

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
  <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
     <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
 <include layout="@layout/wizard_navbar_last" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Update: and I should point out that I'm actually adding the ListView via code like so:

```
ViewGroup page3 = (ViewGroup) 
    findViewById(R.id.wizard_page3_container); //parent linearlayout
page3 = (ViewGroup) page3.getChildAt(0); //linearlayout
LayoutInflater inflater=
    (LayoutInflater) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
folderList = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.wizard_dropbox_list,
                     null);
page3.addView(folderList, 0);
```

Update2: the XML for the navbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/wizard_navbar_last"
  android:paddingTop="20dp"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <include 
    layout="@layout/wizard_previous_button"/>
  <View 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
  <Button
     android:id="@+id/wizard_finish"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Done"
     android:textSize="20dp"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

And previous_button is ... you guessed it, just a button. As for wizard_dropbox_list, it's the ListView as shown here.

Comment: Could you include the contents of `wizard_dropbox_list` and `wizard_navbar_last`?

Comment: Here you go. wizard_dropbox_list is just the ListView as shown here

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the Listview and Navbar in a `RelativeLayout`.  Set the ListView to `alignParentTop="true"` and `layout_height="wrap_content"`, and set the NavBar to `alignParentBottom="true"` and `layout_height="wrap_conent"`.  That should give you the effect you're looking for.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that, in some cases (when the ListView is exactly as tall as the screen), the nav bar will hide the last ListView row. I suppose that the workaround is to add a dummy footer to the ListView that's as tall as the navbar.

Comment: or set paddingBottom on the ListView to be as tall as the navbar. Trying out these approaches and will report back

Comment: no that didn't work. The problem seems to be that RelativeLayout doesn't like to align LinearLayouts that are child views. So the navbar always stays at the top. I thought that the problem was with include but it also fails if I manually add the navbar XML.

Comment: this basic approach works. (1) Put a background on the navbar to hide the overlap. (2) notice that the navbar is a LinearLayout, so to get the alignment to work either change the root of the navbar to a RelativeLayout or wrap the LinearLayout in a RelativeLayout. (3) Use alignParentBottom="true" on the navbar's new RelativeLayout root element. Done. It's a shame there's no way to just get the darn ListView to stop filling the whole screen.